# jQuery filter data by color with option of multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, filter

I am trying to create multiselect filter that can filter data by color.
For example when "Black" is selected only black has to be shown or when "Black" is deselected then all colors should be displayed, or if "Black" and "Blue" is selected then black and blue should be displayed.

**Filter HTML**

```
<ul id="color-filter">    
    <li data-filter="black">Black</li>    
    <li data-filter="blue">Blue</li>
    <li data-filter="brown">Brown</li>
</ul>
```

**Page Body HTML**

```
<div class="material-tiles">
    <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="black" data-popularity="0">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="black" data-popularity="0">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="blue" data-popularity="0">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="blue" data-popularity="0">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="blue" data-popularity="0">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3 samples" data-color="brown" data-popularity="0">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//Materials filter selector script//
    function checkboxSellector (obj) {
        var formCheckbox = obj.find('.form-checkmark');
        var checkBox = obj.find('.checkbox');
        $(function() {
            $(formCheckbox).click(function() {
                $(this).closest(formCheckbox).toggleClass('is-selected');
                $(this).find(checkBox).toggleClass('checkmark');
            });
        });
    }
    checkboxSellector($(this));    

function onGridChangeRequest() {
        $('.material-tiles > .samples').each(function(key, item) {
            item = $(item);
            if (validateByColor(item, selectedColor) && validateByType(item, selectedMaterial)) {
                item.show();
            } else {
                item.hide();
            }
        });
    }
    $('#color-filter > li').on('click', function(e) {
        selectedColor = $(this).data('filter');
        onGridChangeRequest();
    });
```

The filter that I currently have can only select one color at a time and will not reset if unselected, I have tried to change it, but have not much experience with jQuery or javascript.

Help Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $colorFilter = $('#color-filter'),
    $materialTiles = $('.material-tiles'),
    selected = [];

function onGridChangeRequest() {
   selected = [];
   $colorFilter.find('.selected').each(function(i, el) {
     selected.push($(this).attr('data-filter'));
   })

   $materialTiles.find('.samples').each(function(i, el) {
      if(selected.length) {
        if (selected.indexOf($(el).attr('data-color')) !== -1) {
          $(el).show();
          return;
       }
       $(el).hide();
       return;
      }
      $(el).show();
   })
}

$('#color-filter > li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  onGridChangeRequest();
});
```

this is the best thing that i can think of. study the code so you would learn how it works. :D

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution, it works, one question, the list item when selected already has class `.is-selected`, would it be possible to avoid adding another `.selected` class?